# NodeJS "Encoding" URLs into Human-Readable Permalinks

Tags: node.js, escaping

Is there any Node.js library to produce nicely escaped URI's so that they can still be be human readable?

Lets say i have a space or special chars in an URL. If I escape it using `escapeURIComponent()` it will have a lot of %XX chars and i dont want that.

I believe you get the picture..

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How else would you escape a URL?  If you want to do it losslessly, non URL safe characters must be percent encoded, or you need to base64 the entire string.

Comment: I dont mind having lossy URI's as I am working with permalinking and would be willing to make concessions to make my URI's nicer. Think blog posts, for example...

Comment: I see.  You should reword your question, because that's a very different goal than "escaping".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search on npm for "slug" as that is what this type of encoding is called. Here's the first match: https://npmjs.org/package/slug

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I will accept in 4 minutes :-)